# javascript convert string for csv with comma in data

Tags: javascript, csv, encoding

I am generating dynamic csv file with a column name of `name`, `description` etc., In the `description` field has comma so when I opened the csv file it breaks the columns. I need to convert the string with enclosed double quotes.

for eg:

```
name, description, price
SSD, Solid state drive, 100
keyboard,some description with comma, 20
```

I need to convert string with double quote

```
name, description, price
"SSD", "Solid state drive", 100
"keyboard" ,"some description with comma", 20
```

Here the code I used to convert csv:

```
_.each(product, function(obj){
    csvContent += obj.name + "," +obj.desc + "," + obj.price + "\n"
}
```

I feel to adding double quote manually is not good. Is there any function to add double quote to string?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(value)`

Comment: @dandavis if description id `"Beresford NSW", 1958`  it doesnt work well

Comment: can you use tab-delimted instead? there is no "CSV" format, and different apps handle encoding quotes differently, but TSV doesn't have that issue (usually)